# Error during artifact deployment: Problem while unregistering MBean: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am learning java ee. And tried creating simple "hello world" application with model and repository but I got: "" error while trying to deploy to glassfish5. I am using intelliJ.

I thought that it might be because war doesn't compile but when I ran maven from command line it packages everything.

BookRepository.java

```
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "bookStorePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public Book find(Long id){
        return em.find(Book.class, id);
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
    <persistence-unit name="bookStorePU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <class>com.learning.model.Book</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistance.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="bookStoreCreate.ddl"/>
            <property name="javax.persistance.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="bookStoreDrop.ddl"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

I expect it to compile and deploy to glassfish but I get exception:

```
[2019-10-09T11:56:48.412+0200] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/C:/projects/projectname/target/projectname-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_bookStorePU.server] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1570615008412] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Problem while unregistering MBean: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: TopLink:Name=Development-/file_/C_/projects/projectname/target/projectname-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_bookStorePU,Type=Configuration]]

[2019-10-09T11:56:48.414+0200] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/C:/projects/projectname/target/projectname-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_bookStorePU.server] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1570615008414] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Problem while unregistering MBean: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: TopLink:Name=Session(/file_/C_/projects/projectname/target/projectname-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_bookStorePU)]]
```

in glassfish logs